# How can I refine my Actionscript3 Code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a beginner of Actionscript3 and I am doing my homework for finishing a small game, here is the final effect which is eligible: http://neowudesign.com/Ex03_hw.html. In this game, butterfly will avoid being touched by user's cursor. Although I've finished the work, the code is quite awkward since i have little experience in coding. So I am wondering how can I efficient refine my code. Here is my original code:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
var rx:Number = 15;
var ry:Number = 15;
var rwidth:Number = 285;
var rheight:Number = 185;
var rect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(rx,ry,rwidth,rheight);
var velx = 5;
var vely = 5;




stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, avoidMe);

function avoidMe(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("mouseX: "+ mouseX);
trace("mouseY: "+ mouseY);
var point_1:Point = new Point(mouseX,mouseY);
var point_2:Point = new Point(myButterfly.x,myButterfly.y);
var distanceBetween:Number = Point.distance(point_1,point_2);
trace(distanceBetween);// 10

if (distanceBetween < 20 && myButterfly.x >= 15 && myButterfly.x <= 285 && myButterfly.y >= 15 && myButterfly.y <= 185)
{
    if (mouseX < myButterfly.x)
    {
        myButterfly.x +=  velx;
        trace("x is moving left");
    }
    else
    {
        myButterfly.x -=  velx;
        trace("x is moving right");
    }


    if (mouseY < myButterfly.y)
    {
        myButterfly.y +=  vely;
        trace("x is moving down");
    }
    else
    {
        myButterfly.y -=  vely;
        trace("x is moving up");
    }
}

if (myButterfly.x > 285)
{
    myButterfly.x = myButterfly.x - 40;
    trace("hit the right");
}

if (myButterfly.x < 15)
{
    myButterfly.x = myButterfly.x + 40;
    trace("hit the left");
}



if (myButterfly.y > 185)
{
    myButterfly.y = myButterfly.y - 40;
    trace("hit the bottom");
}

if (myButterfly.y < 15)
{
    myButterfly.y = myButterfly.y + 40;
    trace("hit the top");
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to make your code more compact and readable, perform better, be converted to actual classes rather than timeline code?

Comment: Hi, Marty, I want to make my code readable and compact

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compact your code, you may try this :

```
if (distanceBetween < 20 && myButterfly.x >= 15 && myButterfly.x <= 285 && myButterfly.y >= 15 && myButterfly.y <= 185)
{
    myButterfly.x += (mouseX < myButterfly.x) ? velx : velx * -1;

    myButterfly.y += (mouseY < myButterfly.y) ? vely : vely * -1;

    // (expression) ? if expression true : if expression false; 
}

if (myButterfly.x > 285)
{
    myButterfly.x -= 40;
    trace("hit the right");
}

if (myButterfly.x < 15)
{
    myButterfly.x += 40;
    trace("hit the left");
}
```

And so on...

operator ref : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional

Maybe a good idea to type your vars :
var velx:Number = 5;
var vely:Number = 5;

Hope that help.